# Please help me to explain that why " could " is used here

Tags: could

> I was really tired of my old roommate. She ***could*** be so mean.

I thought that *could* in this sentence means *was able to do*.

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: @fev I've done but it's still unclear to me because I thought that "could" in that sentence means " was able to do "

Comment: On this site, you need to show your research and explain clearly what your doubts are. Have a look at the [helpcentre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a particular use of ***can*** (regardless of the tense, past or present):

> You use can to indicate that something is true sometimes or is true in some circumstances.
>
> - Exercising alone ***can*** be boring. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/can))

In your sentence, we understand *she could be so mean* as meaning that she *was* mean, though not all the time. So here *could* is not focused on *ability*, but on expressing something real that happened at times.

[Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/can) says that *can* is

> used to describe *the way a person **sometimes** behaves*
>
> - She ***can*** be very rude at times. [=*she is sometimes very rude*]
>
> used to describe something that *sometimes* or *often* happens
>
> - In this part of the country the weather ***can*** change quickly. [=t*he weather often changes quickly*]

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three possibilities regarding the roommate's meanness:

1. She could be mean
2. She could not be mean
3. She could sometimes be mean

The word ***could*** indicates a *possibility*, but not an *actuality*. For example,

- I *could* say something negative at this point, but I choose not to.
- I *could* be at the top of my class, but unfortunately I lack the motivation to do so.
- Harold *could* go without eating for 48 hours, but he chooses not to fast [that is, to deprive himself of food].

The word ***can*** is sometimes a good substitute for the word ***could***.

- The employees *can* work together as a team, but their boss is too insecure to let them work that way.
- Jim *can* sometimes be outspoken, but his wife encourages him to be silent.
- Cheryl can work independently, but when her boss micro-manages her, the quality of her work suffers.

Whether you use *could* or *can*, each word serves to denote a possibility, but not a *sure* thing.

- The weather *could* prove to be a hindrance to the successful completion of the project.
- The weather *can* sometimes interfere with working outdoors.